# Widget not redrawing on Provider variable change - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have a provider called "FavoritesProvider" which has a variable called "_favoritos" where I store a list of id's.

What I am trying to do, is redraw a ListView widget every time a new item is added or removed to the favorites variable. Here is the function where I do that, where I update the variable and notifyListeners.

```
    Future setFavorites(
    int id,
  ) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String _receivedData = (prefs.getString('favorites') ?? "");
    List _decodedData = [];
    if (_receivedData != "") {
      _decodedData = json.decode(_receivedData);
    }
    String _sentData = "";

    if (_decodedData.contains(id)) {
      _decodedData.remove(id);
      _sentData = json.encode(_decodedData);
    } else {
      _decodedData.add(id);
      _sentData = json.encode(_decodedData);
    }

    prefs.setString("favorites", _sentData);
    _favoritos = _decodedData;
    notifyListeners();
    return _favoritos;}
```

The item I am trying to redraw is nested like this:

- **MainPage**: Scaffold body containing an **IndexedStack**

```
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = [
    HomePage(),
    FavoriteScreen(),
    CompletedScreen()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: _widgetOptions,
        ),
```

- **FavoriteScreen**: Statless widget only containing FavDoneList widget of my own.
- **FavDoneList**: Statefull widget that contains the list. -> **I want to re-render it**.
  I tried using a listener, but it does not redraw:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _favorites = Provider.of<FavoritesProvider>(context).favoritos;

    if (flag == true) {
      if (_favorites.isEmpty) {
        return Center(child: Text("No has añadido favoritos"));
      }

      return ListView(
        children: _loadFavorites(_favorites),
      );
    }
    return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      color: Colors.red,
    ));
  }
```

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? I can't figure out how to redraw it.
Thanks!

Comment: Please add an error message or some indication of what the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: There is no error message @David it is just not updating the Widget as you would expect from a Provider, but it works fine in spite of that!

Comment: I don't see the provider widget anywhere in your widget tree. Are you using the correct version (probably ChangeNotifierProvider)? If so, can you add more of the widget tree to include this?

Comment: Also, you don't show how/where you call setFavorites, that might be useful too. Are you sure the underlying data is actually changing? Try adding a breakpoint and checking if the _decodedData actually contains new information

Comment: @David yeah sorry. The ChangeNotifierProvider is at the root of my app, so it should pass info to all components inside my app.
setFavorites is called in a button apart in another widget. But it works cause once I reload the app, the page is updated. :/ I'll try to update my question today, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using something "ugly":

Since none of my Providers, Consumers or listeners would work, I aimed to reload the whole  **FavDoneList widget** every time the middle bottom tab was pressed. It was a very small price to pay in terms of performance, and it won't affect the user that much.

I did so like this on the Main Page:

```
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
if (index == 1) {
  setState(() {
    _widgetOptions.removeAt(1);
    _widgetOptions.insert(1, FavDoneList(key: UniqueKey()));

    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}}
```

Very important to pass the unique key, otherwise it does not work.